# It it possible to rotate the material to match the normal of the face it's on?

Tags: shader-nodes

I've been starting to look into parallax mapping, mostly to recreate some video game materials for a potential animation. I've managed to get it to work when the mesh is in its default orientation, but the effect completely breaks when I rotate the mesh in any way. Is there a way to rotate the "incoming" vector to always match the mesh rotation, or even the face rotation if possible?
[image]
The (simplified) shader node setup 
*I removed some nodes that didn't contribute to the actual logic of the parallax mapping, to make it easier for other people to easily recreate it*
[image]
The mesh geometry in Edit Mode
[image]
The mesh with the material applied (how it's intended to be seen)
[image]
The same mesh, but rotated 90° on the X axis

Comment: The "value" group input is the scale of the effect, it's currently set to 0.1

Comment: you can base the effect on camera position and rotation, but then a question arises why not do the effect in a shader.

Comment: This is in a shader, I forgot to specify that. This is a node group _in_ the shader

Comment: How would I go about doing the method you mentioned?

Comment: https://mrrolord.gumroad.com/l/BlenderPOM